# ClassName only takes the last item from my array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just starting with reactJS and coding in general. And I can't make it work at this moment:

I'm looping through data with a .map() and I want to give a className that changes with the kind of data I get from my API.

that's why I made an 'if-else' statement that makes an array of what the classNames have to be

But the className always takes the last item

**my if-else statement**

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let Cstyle = []
  if (this.state.results[i].group === 'one') {
    Cstyle = 'one'
  }
  else if (this.state.results[i].group === 'two') {
    Cstyle = 'two'
  }
  else if (this.state.results[i].group === 'three') {
    Cstyle = 'three'
  }
this.setState({style : Cstyle})}
```

**My mapping**

```
{this.state.results.map((res, index) => ( 
  <div key={index} className={'activity' + ' ' + [this.state.style]}>
    <p>res.test</p>
  </div>
))}
```

I expect a list where some items have className= 'one' when I get 'one' from my API, same with 'two' and 'three'.

Comment: className={'activity' + ' ' + this.state.results[index].group}

Comment: Owww.. the answer was so easy and I searched way to far for a solution.. really thanks and sorry for stupid question! @MukeshSoni

Comment: 1. you can replace those three `if` blocks with `Cstyle = this.state.results[i].group;` 2. you'll want `Cstyle[i] = ...` though 3. no need to set state at all, since you can insert the group directly inside the `map` function.

Comment: Like Mukesh said: `className={['activity', res.group].join(' ')}` and `<p>{res.test}</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for` loop, you can directly use the group name as a class name

```
{this.state.results.map((res, index) => ( 
    <div key={index} className={`activity ${res.group}`}>
    <p>res.test</p>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is the shortest useable answer and I didn't see it at all. really apreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let Cstyle = []
> ```

`Cstyle` starts out life as an array…

> ```
>  Cstyle = 'one'
> ```

… but inside the loop you repeatedly overwrite it with a string.

---

If you want to add something to the array, use its `push()` method. Don't overwrite it.

```
Cstyle.push('one');
```

And create the array **before** the loop, not inside it.

---

*Aside*: Idiomatic JavaScript reserves variable names beginning with a capital letter for constructor functions / classes. Don't use that naming convention for a variable that holds an array or a string.

Answer (score 1):

As Cstyle is array you are reassigning it with a string variable.

You have to add style into that array not reassign it.

**use : Cstyle.push('one')  or Cstyle[i] = 'one' to add value inside array.**

```
  let Cstyle = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  if(this.state.results[i].group === 'one'){
    Cstyle.push('one');
    }
    else if(this.state.results[i].group === 'two'){
    Cstyle.push('two');
    }
    else if(this.state.results[i].group === 'three'){
    Cstyle.push('three');
}
this.setState({style : Cstyle})}
```

Comment: Thanks! helps a lot for understanding!

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the array `Cstyle` in the loop, therefore by it will only ever contain the last item you put in it.

However you are assigning a string value to the array overwriting the array and thus contains the last string